# Extracting numbers from the next sibling's text

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup, nlp

I would like to assign each number to the suitable tag in python2.7. In the below example, I had 2 numbers and 2 tags. I cannot iterate element of next_siblings which might be the case because of NavigableString type. However, how could i handle this problem if i cannot ?
Thanks

Edit: I cannot search based on div tags, because names and numbers could be in entirely different html tags. Hence, i do not want to restrict on this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    tempHtml = """
    <html>
        <body>
            <div>
                <h1>tag1</h1>
                aaaa
                <div class="tel">here is 0111 111 1111 <span class="note">*</span></div>
                <h1>tag2</h1>
                <div class="tel mob">0111 222 2222 <span class="note">**</span></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    """

soup = BeautifulSoup(tempHtml, 'html.parser')
extracted = soup.find_all(['h1'])
for i in range(len(extracted)):
    for sibling in extracted[i].next_siblings:
        tagname = extracted[i].text.strip()
        number_with_text = extracted[i].next_element
        number = re.findall('\d+', number_with_text)
        number = ''.join(number)
        print(str(number) + ' >> ' + str(tagname))
```

Expected output :

```
0111 111 1111 >> tag1
0111 222 2222 >> tag2
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(extracted)):` is very un-Pythonic. You should use `for i in extracted:`.

Comment: @DYZ thanks for your suggestion, will do use it like that. However, it is not related with the main issue, i think.

Comment: If an answer meets your requirements you should, please, mark it 'accepted'.

Comment: Please have a look my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

Find the list of `h1`-`div` siblings. Then in each case, ferret out the phone number from the text of the `div`, and get the `text` of the previous sibling of the `div`.

```
>>> tempHtml = open('temp.htm').read()
>>> import bs4
>>> for div in soup.select('h1 ~ div'):
...     bs4.re.search(r'([0-9][0-9 ]{12})', div.text).groups(0)[0], '>>', div.findPreviousSibling().text
...     
... 
('0111 111 1111', '>>', 'tag1')
('0111 222 2222', '>>', 'tag2')
```

Comment: I am expecting more dynamic solutions instead of looking specific tags using child, parent, sibling. The given scenario is only an example problem for my case. For instance, instead of div tag, it could be different tag. For h1, again it is the same, can be h1, h2, ... , strong and so on. Because of those reasons I have not label it as an accepted. Thanks

Comment: @user2274826: If that's the case then you should make it clear in your question, not in comments to answers. We can't guess what you want.